# Jquery effect to show overflow text of a <li><a> menu element on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a very normal css hover menu, with LOTS of href's into it.
The problem is, every sub-cell of the menu, if hovered, shows up a little white-backgrounded "box" that will hold the elements of the hovered father. Here's an example, with FATHER1 hovered ( the menu is completely CSS-driven ):

```
_____________________________
FATHER1 | FATHER 2 | FATHER 3
________|__________|_________
.--^-------------------------------
|Title Of Cont1    Title Of Cont2  |
| Lia element        Lia element   |
| Lia element        Lia element   |
| Lia element        Lia element   |    ( "Lia element" stands for <li><a> )
|                                  |
|Title of Cont3    Title of Cont4  |
| Lia element        Lia element   |
| Lia element        Lia element   |
'----------------------------------'
```

Here's the problem: this way, when a <li><a> element exceeds a certain number of pixels in width ( in my case, the number is 156px ), the layout breaks because of no more height parallelism.

The solution is simple, via CSS on the <li><a> elements:

```
display: block; width: 156px; overflow: hidden; white-space:nowrap;
```

This way, all the overflowing text from pixel 156 to infinite, stays hidden.

Now, I need a second step to my project: when a user passes over with the mouse on these "stripped" <li><a>'s elements, I would like to show him the rest of the text, in a "carousel-like" way, letter by letter.
So, the width stays 156px at every time, but the user can actually see what is the hidden text.

Any fancy way to do this? I've never saw such a piece of code in my life, and I'm stuck with google keywords, in this case

Comment: Do you really want this kind of "carousel-like" behavior? Because you can simply display the full content with a simple tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something along these lines:

```
.menu *{
    -webkit-transition  : all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition     : all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition       : all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition      : all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.item{
    width               : 100px;
    line-height         : 20px;
    height              : 20px;
    border              : 1px solid red;
    display             : block;
    overflow            : hidden;
    cursor              : pointer;
}
.item a{
    position            : relative;
    display             : block;
    text-decoration     : none;
    height              : 20px;
    white-space         : nowrap;
}
.item:hover a{
    -webkit-transform   : translate(-100%, 0px);
    -moz-transform      : translate(-100%, 0px);
    -o-transform        : translate(-100%, 0px);
    -ms-transform       : translate(-100%, 0px);
}
</style>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">somewhat longer item 2</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

you can do a similar thing using javascript of course

Comment: Thank you for your help Matthijs!
You showed me a technique I was completely unaware of, that's brilliant :)
Do you know any way to replicate the same effect with css + jquery, to make it browser compliant? Unfortunately, I have to run this piece of code in a website that is visited with a vast number of different browsers and versions... :(

Answer (score 1):

After having searched the web and the jQuery documentation deeply, I've found a solution:

CSS ( fix width & height of the elements to fit your needs )

```
#nav ul.sub_cat li { display: block; width: 156px; overflow: hidden; height: 13px; }
#nav ul.sub_cat li a { display: block; position: relative; height: 13px; white-space: nowrap; }
```

jQuery snippet

- I'm filtering the li's that need auto-scroll functionality with rel="filter"
- I'm using "22" as breakdown li text length to trigger the animation
- I'm using a factor of 8px for each character overflowing the 22 char breakdown

Obviously, change these values to fit your needs

```
$('ul li[rel="filter"]').hover (
    function() {
        var lihref = $(this).find('a');
        var lihreftextlengthbreakdown = 22;
        var pixelfactor = 8;

        if ( $(lihref).text().length > lihreftextlengthbreakdown ) {
            var slidelen = ( ( $(lihref).text().length ) - lihreftextlengthbreakdown ) * pixelfactor;
            $(this).animate ( { scrollLeft: slidelen }, 5000 );
        }
    },
    function() {
        $(this).animate ({ scrollLeft: 0 });
    }
);
```